# Weighted average distribution algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, distribution

I have **N** buckets, each with a normalized weight of **W<sub>i</sub>**. I would like to distribute $**x** to each bucket by its weight. Each bucket has a minimum $ (**MIN<sub>i</sub>**) and maximum $ (**MAX<sub>i</sub>**) that the algorithm needs to fulfill. The min and max of each buckets take priorities over the weights. Is this problem solvable in polynomial time and how does the algorithm look like?

Example:

4 buckets, A, B, C, D

A: W<sub>A</sub> = 100, MIN<sub>A</sub> = 0, MAX<sub>A</sub> = 150

B: W<sub>B</sub> = 100, MIN<sub>B</sub> = 0, MAX<sub>B</sub> = 60

C: W<sub>C</sub> = 1, MIN<sub>C</sub> = 20, MAX<sub>C</sub> = 150

D: W<sub>D</sub> = 1, MIN<sub>D</sub> = 30, MAX<sub>D</sub> = 150

Total $ = $150

Expected Result:

A: $50

B: $50

C: $20

D: $30

Note that C and D are using their mins and the rest of the dollars are split evenly because A and B have the same weight.

Comment: What do you mean by "the min and max take priority over the weights"? Are we allowed to have leftover money? If bucket A had a max of $25, would you want buckets A and B to only have $25 in them, since their weights are equal, or do we continue adding money to B?

Comment: Leftovers are not allowed. Max and min only applies to the individual bucket. So if A maxed out at 25 dollars, B can still go higher because it didn't hit is max. Weight should be applied if caps are not hit in an ad set level.

Comment: @collapsar You might as well turn that into an answer.

Comment: You have correctly proven my beautiful algorithm wrong ... answer retracted ;-). However, I still think that a solution in polynomial time is possible. Rephrase the problem as a linear programming problem.

Comment: And retracting another claim  for the time being ... sorry didin't think that throough thoroughly enough.

Comment: @collaspar What was wrong with it, out of curiosity? I just glanced at it, but I didn't catch anything wrong.

Comment: A: W=40, Min=42, Max=55. B: W=40, Min=0, Max=100. C: W=20, Min=0, Max=4. Expected result: A: 48, B: 48, C: 4. collaspar's algorithm gives A: 42, B: 54, C: 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let z be a real parameter. My understanding of the problem is that you want to find z such that, when bucket i is allocated max(MIN<sub>i</sub>, min(MAX<sub>i</sub>, W<sub>i</sub> z)), the sum of allocations equals x.

Here's an O(n log n)-time algorithm (there's probably a linear-time one, but if it does exist it's likely to be more complicated). Intuitively what it does is to increase z continuously until the sum of allocations equals x.

The derivative of the sum in z is the sum of the derivatives for each bucket. The derivative of bucket i is 0 for z < a, then W<sub>i</sub> for a < z < b, then 0 for b < z, where a = MIN<sub>i</sub> / W<sub>i</sub> is the first critical point, and b = MAX<sub>i</sub> / W<sub>i</sub> is the second critical point. We sort these critical points and then trace out the resulting piecewise linear function. In Python 3 (intentionally avoiding some Python idioms):

```
import collections

Bucket = collections.namedtuple('Bucket', ('weight', 'min', 'max'))
Event = collections.namedtuple('Event', ('key', 'i', 'derivative'))


def allocate(total, buckets):
  n = len(buckets)
  events = []
  derivative = 0
  residual = total
  derivatives = []
  for i in range(n):
    bucket = buckets[i]
    events.extend([Event(bucket.min / bucket.weight, i, bucket.weight),
                   Event(bucket.max / bucket.weight, i, 0)])
    residual -= bucket.min
    derivatives.append(0)
  events.sort()
  z = 0
  for event in events:
    if derivative > 0:
      w = z + residual / derivative
      if w <= event.key:
        z = w
        break
    residual -= derivative * (event.key - z)
    derivative -= derivatives[event.i]
    derivatives[event.i] = event.derivative
    derivative += derivatives[event.i]
    z = event.key
  allocations = []
  for i in range(n):
    bucket = buckets[i]
    allocations.append(max(bucket.min,
                           min(bucket.max,
                               bucket.weight * z)))
  return allocations

print(allocate(150,
               [Bucket(100, 0, 150),
                Bucket(100, 0, 60),
                Bucket(1, 20, 150),
                Bucket(1, 30, 150)]))
# [50.0, 50.0, 20, 30]
print(allocate(100,
               [Bucket(40, 42, 55),
                Bucket(40, 0, 100),
                Bucket(20, 0, 4)]))
# [48.0, 48.0, 4]
```

Comment: Looking at your explanation above the algorithm. What are 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: @eymlo "where a = MINi / Wi is the first critical point, and b = MAXi / Wi is the second critical point"

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Assign all min budgets

```
in your example: 
( 0, 0, 20 ,30)
```

Step 2: Calculate ideal assignments if there were no boundaries:

```
in your example: 
(100/202)*150 =74
(100/202)*150 =74
(1/202)*150 = 0.74
(1/202)*150 = 0.74
```

Step 3: Subtract what is "current assignment" from the ideal:

```
in your example:
0 - 74 = -74
0 - 74 = -74
20 - 0.74 = 19.26
30 - 0.74 = 29.26
```

Step 4: Assign a dollar/cent to the lowest value in step 3

```
in your example:
-74 is the lowest value
so just assign a dollar to the first one with the lowest value
```

Step 5: Repeat steps 3 and 4 and stop allocating budgets to a bucket that reaches its cap.